How to download an encrypted file with ANSI encoding in Javascript?
I'm trying to download a file in javascript using axios like below
axios
.put("https://example.com/api/", fileContent, {
  headers: {
  responseType: "blob",
  }
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log("Original File :", response.data);

const href = window.URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob([response.data], {
    type: "application/octet-stream;charset=ANSI",
  }), 
);
const fileName = response.headers["content-disposition"]
  .split("filename=")[1]
  .split(";")[0];
  
// create "a" HTML element with href to file & click
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = href;
link.setAttribute("download", fileName); //or any other extension
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();

// clean up "a" element & remove ObjectURL
document.body.removeChild(link);
URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
});

This is downloading a file which is not in ANSI encoding it is in UTF-8, so that my encrypted file is not able to decrypt.
If i try the same on postman via send and download that file it is in ANSI encoding Please check below images.

I tried converting UTF-8 to ANSI but it didn't help.
import { utf8ToAnsi } from "utf8-to-ansi";

.then((response) => {
    var blob = new Blob([utf8ToAnsi(response.data)], {
      type: "application/json;charset=ANSI",
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "FileSave_utftoAnsi.json");
  });

My response header are like this


How postman will be able to save the file and not via Javascript?
